# Quartz Composer "Binding Controls to Input Ports" in Xcode 4.x

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, xcode4.2, cocoa-bindings, quartz-composer

I am trying to follow "Binding Controls to Input Ports" of [Quartz Composer Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzComposer/qc_play_ib_input/qc_play_ib_input.html).

The document says :

> 5.Click “Bind to” and then choose Patch Controller in the “Bind to” popup menu.
>
> 6.Enter patch in the Controller Key text field.
>
> 7.Enter text.value in the Model Key Path text field.

In my project of Xcode (4.2 &) 4.3, the Controller Key text field is disabled. The Model Key Path text field requires an object of QCPatch class, which I don't think I have a clue.

Should I install Xcode 3.x and handle this & convert to 4.x? Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issues, however via the kineme forums I have found a work around:

using the Object Controller instead of the Qc Patch Controller:

1. make a new cocoa project...
2. add quartz framework via buid phases tab and import the framework to your project either in the pre compile header, or app delegate...
3. add qc view to your xib and load your composition
4. add object controller to your xib...
5. change object controllers class to "QCView" without quotes.
6. control drag your object controller to your qc view and select "content"
7. add a slider and bind its value to your object controller and set its model key path to "patch.Text.value" without quotes.....

see [this](http://kineme.net/forum/DevelopingCompositions/ProblemusingQCPatchController) for the full thread on this topic.

Comment: BTW, how can I bind a published port of the patch among many others?

Answer (score 0):

in xib file choose the QCView

Attibutes Inspector -> check **"Forwards All Events"**

hope it helps